# Cannot run more than two tasks in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have two clusters in my Amazon Elastic Container Service, one for production and one as a testing environment.

Each cluster has three different services with one task each. There should be 6 tasks running.

To update a task, I always pushed my new Docker Image to the Elastic Container Registry and restarted the Service with the new Image.

Since about 2 weeks I am only able to start 2 Tasks at all. It doesn't depend on the cluster, just 2 Tasks in general.

[image]

It looks like the tasks that should start are stuck in the "In Progress" Rollout State.
[image]

Has anybody similar problem or knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the Events tab?

Comment: not till now, it says:  "You've reached the limit on the number of tasks you can run concurrently"
Do you know where I can set that limit?

Comment: Is it a new aws account?

Comment: Not really, I run the account since September 2020, and it already worked with more than 2 running tasks

Comment: can you got to `AWS Service Quotas` console, and check Farget limits?

Comment: Fargate On-Demand resource count: 100 / 1000
Fargate Spot resource count: 250 / 1000

Comment: and ECS limits?

Comment: Every option has "not available" out of 10.000, 2.000, 5.000, 5.000

Answer (score 4):

I wrote to the support with this issue.

"After a review, I have noticed that the XXXXXXX region has not yet been activated. In order to activate the region you will have to launch an instance, I recommended a Free Tier EC2 instance.

After the EC2 instance has been launched you can terminate it thereafter.
"

I don't know why, but it's working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks Przemek Sosnowski, this fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed for me, thanks!

Comment: @HaraldHoerwick what did you exactly do to fix it? I don't really get this answer.

Comment: Inside the AWS console page, search for EC2, create a new instance of type t2.micro. Launch your instance, wait some time and you should be able to launch more than two tasks.